# ORA-00942 When using GPars withPool in Groovy

Tags: oracle, hibernate, groovy, concurrency, gpars

I currently process a paginated list with the following command:

```
paginatedList.each { it.update() }
```

However this is slow and I'd like to leverage GPars to update each item concurrently.

I have used:

```
GParsPool.withPool {
    paginatedList.eachParallel { it.update() }
}
```

However when I run this I get:

```
Message: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The code runs serially for any number of items in the list, but it wont work concurrently for any number even if there is only one item in paginatedList.

The update function calls in data from several tables/views and other tables/views work fine but it stops on one particular view. The query it is trying works fine when executed manually (and is the same as when called serially, which works).

Can anyone help with why this doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing this is something to do with Hibernate being bound to the main thread, and not the threads that GPars is running on...  I'll have a look around

Comment: Actually, not sure Hibernate sessions are thread safe for use across threads